# Maping inside a map - Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Coding noob here :)

I'm working on a project where I have prepared an array that I'm mapping over and printing. Inside the array I have another array, called "lang", that I can't reach from the map. I want to print each item in that array into an `<li>`, as the code is now all the items are printed as one `<li>` , which I don't want. I have tried maping inside the map in various ways but not gotten it to work.

Is the right way to do a map inside the map? In that case, how is it done?

Is there another way to do this?

Please see part of the array and the map function I have created down below. projectContainer, which I'm adding the innerHTML to, is a div inside the index.html file.

```
    },
    {
      img: "./pictures/guess-who.png",
      projectTitle: 'GUESS WHO?',
      projectDescription: 'Recreation of the game "Guess who?" built with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.',
      lang: [
        'HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'
      ],
      url: '',
      className: '',
      id: 6
    }
  ]
  }

  const printProjects = () => {

    projectArray.projects.map((project) => {
      projectContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="project-container ${project.id}">
          <img src=${project.img} alt="picture of guess who game"></img>
          <h4>${project.projectTitle}</h4>
          <p>${project.projectDescription}</p>
          <ul>
            <li>${project.lang} </li>
          </ul
        </div>
        `
    })
  }

  printProjects()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and use map(...).join('')

```
 <ul>
  ${project.lang.map(el => `
    <li>${el}</li>
  `).join('')}
</ul>
```